# How to include data aurgument within custom R function?

Tags: r, function

I want to include data argument within a custom R function. Right now I am using the following function

```
Ploy <- function(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width, 
                 Petal.Width = Petal.Width, Petal.Length = Petal.Length){
  
  #Calculate some derived parameters
  deltak <- (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width)/390
  ARk <- Petal.Width*2
  
  dat <- cbind.data.frame(deltak, ARk)
  
  #Fitting quadratic model
  mod <- lm(deltak ~ poly(ARk, 2, raw = TRUE))
  
  deltaK0 <- abs(mod$coefficients[[1]])
  
  Ks <- Petal.Length - deltaK0
  
  return(c(`DeltaK0` = deltaK0, `Ks` = Ks))
}
```

When I am calling the function I have to use `iris$` like

```
Ploy(Sepal.Length = iris$Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width = iris$Sepal.Width, 
     Petal.Width = iris$Petal.Width, Petal.Length = iris$Petal.Length)
```

I know there is a workaround using `with` like

```
with(iris, Ploy(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width, 
                Petal.Width = Petal.Width, Petal.Length = Petal.Length))
```

But I want to have the call for the `Ploy` function like

```
Ploy(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width, 
     Petal.Width = Petal.Width, Petal.Length = Petal.Length, data = iris)
```

How can I achieve it?

**Update**

Taking clue from the answer of @user2554330, I have used the following code

```
Ploy <- function(data, Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
                 Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length"){
  
  Sepal.Length = data[[Sepal.Length]]
  Sepal.Width = data[[Sepal.Width]]
  Petal.Width = data[[Petal.Width]]
  Petal.Length = data[[Petal.Length]]

  #Calculate some derived parameters
  deltak <- (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width)/390
  ARk <- Petal.Width*2
  
  dat <- cbind.data.frame(deltak, ARk)
  
  #Fitting quadratic model
  mod <- lm(deltak ~ poly(ARk, 2, raw = TRUE))
  
  deltaK0 <- abs(mod$coefficients[[1]])
  
  Ks <- Petal.Length - deltaK0
  
  return(c(`DeltaK0` = deltaK0, `Ks` = Ks))
}
```

Now the function can be used like

```
Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
     Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", data = iris)
```

Comment: `Ploy <- function(myData){...}` When calling the function provide the data, not the column names `Ploy(iris)`, then in the function work with column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is "non-standard evaluation":  you don't want to evaluate the expression `Sepal.Length` in the standard way.

I'd advise against doing this.  It's very difficult to get it right, so that you don't have weird behavior in some special cases.  The tidyverse packages use it, and even though those packages are written by very smart people who have thought about it very carefully, it still has some weird bugs, e.g. handling `...` arguments.

Instead, ask your user to specify the column using a string name, e.g. their call looks like

```
Ploy(col1 = "Sepal.Length", col2 = "Sepal.Width", 
 col3 = "Petal.Width", data = iris)
```

Then within your function, using entirely standard evaluation, you can refer to those columns as

```
data[[col1]]
data[[col2]]
data[[col3]]
```

Comment: @UseR10085, you can use whatever names you like, but to follow this advice the names should be fixed.  It wouldn't really make sense to use the name `Sepal.Length` with `data = mtcars`.

Comment: I don't think you should make such a big change to a question that was posted more than a year ago.  Ask a new question if you want to ask something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify as many parameters (inputs) to your R functions as you like.
The problem you encounter is **because of how you are calling those parameters** (inputs).

An example of a function statement might be as follows:

```
# Function declaration
Ploy <- function(sepal_lenght,sepal_width, petal_witdh, petal_length, data){
   print(paste("sepal_lenght inside function is ", sepal_lenght))
   print(paste("sepal_width inside function is ", sepal_width))
   print(paste("petal_witdh inside function is ", petal_witdh))
   print(paste("petal_length inside function is ", petal_length))
  print(paste("Aditional data inside function is ", data))
}

# Running your function with concrete values
Ploy(10,20,3.4,66, 'complex object')
```

An example result would be:

```
[1] "sepal_lenght inside function is  10"
[1] "sepal_width inside function is  20"
[1] "petal_witdh inside function is  3.4"
[1] "petal_length inside function is  66"
[1] "Aditional data inside function is  complex object"
```

That said, for your case, you could perform a function like this:

```
sepal  <- data.frame(
  "length" = 5.1, 
  "width" = 3.5
)

petal  <- data.frame(
  "length" = 1,4, 
  "width" = 0.2
)

# Function declaration
Ploy <- function(sepal, petal, data){
   print(paste("sepal_lenght inside function is ", sepal$length))
   print(paste("sepal_width inside function is ", sepal$width))
   print(paste("petal_witdh inside function is ", petal$length))
   print(paste("petal_length inside function is ", petal$width))
  print(paste("Aditional data inside function is ", data))
}

# Running your function with concrete values, passing sepal and petal objects
Ploy(sepal, petal, 'more complex object')
```

So you will obtain:

```
[1] "sepal_lenght inside function is  5.1"
[1] "sepal_width inside function is  3.5"
[1] "petal_witdh inside function is  1"
[1] "petal_length inside function is  0.2"
[1] "Aditional data inside function is  more complex object"
```